# Paypal Smart buttons with Javascript and fetch to a PHP page

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am having an intermittent problem with some Javascript code whch I cannot seem to solve and would appreciate any help with.

I have a campsite booking page which utilizes Paypal smart buttons to effect payment. In part of the Paypal Javascript 'create order' code I extract the entered customer details, populate a form using Javascript and then use fetch to post the info to a server side PHP page which inserts the info into a database.

The problem is this seems to fail 40-50% of the time ie Paypal payment is made sucessfully but the database insert appears to not be triggered.

The Javascript code is below. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Neville

```html
                                      <script>
                                      
                                      var fname="";
                                      var sname="";
                                      var email="";
                                      var mobile="";
                                      var invoice_id="";                                      
                
                                      paypal.Buttons({
                                        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                                          // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                                          
                                          //1. validate form details, abort if incorrrect
                                           if (validateForm()==false) {
                                                alert("Incorrect Booking form data provided, aborting payment function.\r\n\r\nPlease recheck Booking form data and resubmit.");
                                                //actions.disable();
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                            
                                            //2. extract customer info from webpage
                                            try {

                                                email = document.forms["bookingform"]["email"].value;
                                                invoice_id=document.forms["bookingform"]["invoice_id"].value;
                                                
                                                fname= document.forms["bookingform"]["fname"].value;
                                                sname = document.forms["bookingform"]["sname"].value;
                                                mobile = document.forms["bookingform"]["mobile"].value; 
                                                                                                
                                                if (invoice_id=="") {
                                                    invoice_id= sname.toUpperCase();
                                                    invoice_id=invoice_id+"   ";
                                                    invoice_id=invoice_id.substring(0,3)+"-";
                                                    invoice_id=invoice_id+(100000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000));
                                                    invoice_id=invoice_id.substring(0,10);
                                                    document.forms["bookingform"]["invoice_id"].value=invoice_id;
                                                }
                                                
                                            
                                                var tot_night = document.getElementById('tot_nights').innerHTML;
            
                                                var tot_amt=document.getElementById("tot_amt").innerHTML;
                                                tot_amt = tot_amt.replace("$", "");

                                                var date_from = document.forms["bookingform"]["date_from"].value;
                                                var date_to = document.forms["bookingform"]["date_to"].value;
                                                var vehicle_rego = document.forms["bookingform"]["vehicle_rego"].value;
                                                var no_adults = document.forms["bookingform"]["no_adults"].value;
                                                var no_children = document.forms["bookingform"]["no_children"].value;
                                                var power = document.forms["bookingform"]["power"].checked;
                                                var tent_hire = document.forms["bookingform"]["tent_hire"].checked;
                                                
            
                                                if (power=='true' || power==true) {
                                                    power ="Yes";
                                                } else {
                                                    power="No";
                                                }
                                                if (tent_hire=='true' || tent_hire==true) {
                                                    tent_hire ="Yes";
                                                } else {
                                                    tent_hire="No";
                                                }
                                                                                                
                                                var street_address = document.forms["bookingform"]["street_address"].value;
                                                var locality = document.forms["bookingform"]["locality"].value;
                                                var package_type = document.forms["bookingform"]["package_type"].value
                                                var voucher = document.forms["bookingform"]["voucher"].value
                                                var notes = document.forms["bookingform"]["notes"].value
                                                
                                                //$('#ref_fld').val(details.id);
                                                $('#ref_fld').val('0');

                                            } catch(err) {}
                                            
                                            //3. create form, insert data
                                               var formdata = new FormData(); 
                                            
                                                if (formdata) {
                                                
                                                        try {
       
                                                            formdata.append("post_function","make_booking");
                                                            
                                                            formdata.append("notes", notes);
                                                            formdata.append("invoice_id", invoice_id);
                                                            formdata.append("voucher", voucher);
                                                            formdata.append("package_type", package_type);
                                                            
                                                            street_address=street_address.replace('"', '');
                                                            street_address=street_address.replace("'", "");
                                                            notes=notes.replace('"', '');
                                                            notes=notes.replace("'", "");
                                                            
                                                            formdata.append("locality", locality);
                                                            formdata.append("street_address", street_address);
                                                            formdata.append("vehicle_rego",vehicle_rego);
                                                            formdata.append("trans_id",'0');
                                                            formdata.append("tot_amt",tot_amt);
                                                            formdata.append("tot_night",tot_night);
                                                            formdata.append("tent_hire",tent_hire);
                                                            formdata.append("power",power);
                                                            formdata.append("no_children",no_children);
                                                            formdata.append("no_adults",no_adults);
                                                            formdata.append("date_to",date_to);
                                                            formdata.append("date_from",date_from);
                                                            formdata.append("mobile",mobile);
                                                            formdata.append("email",email);
                                                            formdata.append("sname",sname);
                                                            formdata.append("fname",fname);
                                                        
                                                        } catch(err) {}
                                                        
                                            //4. post form 
                                                        
                                                        const url = '/includes_macas/mysql_functions.php';
                                                        fetch(url, {
                                                            method: 'POST',
                                                            body: formdata
                                                        }).catch(function(error) {
                                                            console.log(error); // Display error if there is one.
                                                        })

 
                                                }                                           
                                                                                                                                                            
                                          return actions.order.create({
                                           payer: {
                                            name: {
                                              given_name: fname,
                                              surname: sname
                                            },
                                            email_address: email,
                                            phone: {
                                              phone_type: "MOBILE",
                                              phone_number: {
                                                national_number: mobile
                                              }
                                            }
                                          },
                                            purchase_units: [{
                                            invoice_id: invoice_id,
                                              amount: {
                                                value: tot_amt
                                              }
                                            }],      
                                            application_context: {
                                                shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
                                                }
                                          });
                                        },
                                        onClick: function() {
                                            //$('#wait').show();
                                        },
                                        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                                  
                                  
                                  .......
```

Comment: If you view the "Network" tab in the browser console, is the POST request submitting each time a payment is received?

Comment: hi, thanks for your interest. a large part of the problem is that i cannot reproduce the 'error'. every time i test the booking form either in the dev or live environment, it works as intended. i have also put in fairly extensive error trapping which also has not help identify the error. it appears only when other parties use the live form the fetch /post fails approx 50% of the time.

Comment: Could you please post the entire HTML document so I can see what's happening?

Comment: the entire page can be found at https://booking.macas.a2hosted.com/booking.php

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use the (as of 2023 now deprecated) `actions.order.create() / .capture()` on the client side and then record to a database, since there is no guarantee of being able to record a successful capture on your server if you do that.

Instead, for a proper server integration, create two routes -- one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', as documented in [the standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) Your routes should return/output JSON (and only JSON). The capture route should check for success after calling PayPal and do any database writing before returning JSON to the client.

Pair your two routes with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: got it, thanks for that. one question tho, if the actions. order. create is straight javascript, why is there no guarantee that my code ie. the fetch would not execute. just sounds very wierd. kinda flies in the face of having code that can be executed regularly and reliably.

Comment: It's client-side in the browser